# Kubernetes: Follow kubectl proxy logs

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to see what traffic is going through `kubectl proxy`? For example HTTP request, response.

Is it possible to follow that log (kind of `-f`)?

Comment: Have you already tried turning up the verbosity of `kubectl`? With the verbosity turned up around `--v=10`, it will certainly log every interaction it has with the apiserver, so it's possible it will do the same for `proxy`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel: Neither `kubectl --v=10 proxy` nor `kubectl -v=10 proxy` work :(.

Comment: If you're open to using [an intercepting proxy](https://mitmproxy.org/), you can likely capture the traffic that way, too, which actually should be even easier than usual because the trusted CA is listed in `~/.kube/config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl --v=10 proxy` follows the log.